# MySQL fails to add days to a date when month is over

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures

I am trying to get a final date when a number of days (**pplazo** input) has elapsed, starting on a date (**pfecha** input), and avoiding to count certain dates (**feriado**) that are listed on a table.

So far this is what i got to, using a Stored Procedure:

**Input parameters:**

pfecha -- DATE

pplazo -- INT (11)

```
PROC:BEGIN

DECLARE i INT(1);

START TRANSACTION;

SET i=1;

lazo:LOOP
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM feriados WHERE feriado=pfecha+i)
        THEN
        SET pfecha=pfecha+1;
        SET i=i+1;
    END IF;

    IF i=pplazo
        THEN
        LEAVE lazo;
    END IF;
END LOOP lazo;

COMMIT;

SELECT pfecha as respuesta;

END
```

The thing is, when the days to count make the date go pass the end of the month, then the "**respuesta**" turns to 0000-00-00.
This shouldn't be happening, if I input 15 days starting on the 2016-04-20 then the resulting date should be something like 2016-05-5.

Can you spot my mistake? Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `DATE_ADD(pfecha, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.

Comment: Do you really want to add 1 to both `pfecha` and `i`? That will make your query jump by 2 days each time through the loop.

Comment: @Drew that is because i ended up not using any of their answers... should i pick the best answer anyway? awkward.

Comment: If you found one of them helpful, you could upvote em. You could always just put a comment in your questions saying "hey I solved it." Better yet, you could do a self-answer and show what you did. That way, (1) people could review and maybe give suggestions .... (2) it alerts people to not waste their time reading it, the op is happy, let's all move on to other stuff

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite loop. If the `SELECT` query finds a matching row you don't increment `i`. If `i != pplazo`, you repeat the loop and do the same query again.

Comment: @Barmar you got it right ... `DATE_ADD(pfecha, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` was the solution

Comment: Done @Drew . You were right. My bad.

Comment: I've seen worse. Sorry, I guess I was edgey :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to add a number of days to a date is with the [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) or [`ADDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) functions, not the `+` operator. See

```
lazo:LOOP
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM feriados WHERE feriado=DATE_ADD(pfecha, INTERVAL i DAY))
        THEN
        SET pfecha=DATE_ADD(pfecha, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        SET i=i+1;
    END IF;

    IF i=pplazo
        THEN
        LEAVE lazo;
    END IF;
END LOOP lazo;
```